# Could not click the "Close" button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">    
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
        <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-text">    
                Close    
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>    
</div>

browser.find_element_by_link_text('Close').click()
```

What is this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Close" button is not a link but a `<span>`, so don't use `find_element_by_link_text`.

What exception did you get? I assume you have a 'NoSuchElementException', then without seeing more HTML, I can't give you the best locators, because you might have more spans with text `Close`, messy whitespaces, or many other spans with same class name `ui-button`.

But please try this (assume you have only one Close button without messy whitespaces):

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[text()='Close']").click()
```

**EDIT**: Given the website is http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/, the problem is you have more "Close" buttons, which are not visible, so you need better XPath.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='notificationArea']/..//span[text()='Close']").click()
```

Comment: ElementNotVisibleException though i applied 10s sleep

Comment: @neha: As I said, I assume you have one Close button, but it looks like you have few more. Please try change XPath to `.//*[@id='notificationArea']/..//span[text()='Close']`